# TestRestTemplate doesn't detect the resouce which has been mocked in a SpringBootTest

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot, mocking, mockito, resttemplate

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnitRunner.class)    
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOMPORT)   
class ResourceTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;

    @MockBean
    private AuthService authService; //This is used in the method being hit by the testRestTemplate.

    @Before
    public void setUp() extends Exception {
        given(this.authService.auth(user)).willReturn(user); //given mock object some behaviour
        //Some Code
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuthValidParameters() throws Exception {
        //Assume Every Parameter is appropriate
        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<>(postBody,headers);
        //The Exception occurs here
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = this.testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/path/auth/",request,String.class);
        //Some asserts and other tests
    }
}
```

The exception is as follows

```
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "http://localhost:53234/path/auth/"
```

The problem doesn't occur when I don't Mock and let the actual methods run or I use Mock directly (seems like Normal Mock in combination with PowerMock doesn't actually effect the method being called). They are executed and this is being integrated test which doesn't solve the problem.

So, when I use MockBean this exception arises. What might be the root cause and how could I solve it.

---

Edit 1:

Using almost same code and changing the mock stubbing in setUp like

```
when(authService.authenticate(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user);
```

I get a Http Code 400. Does this mean it is hitting the server? Which might imply that it is picking up the MockBean but the parameters which haven't been changed at all are being rejected.

Answer (score -1):

You may write something like below to let your mock service return some response.

```
    User user= new User();
    user.setUserName("abc");
    user.setPassword("testPass");
    when(authService.authenticate(user)).thenReturn(user);
```

You can then invoke the testRestTemplate and post your object and expect this response in return.

Define Restassured port :

```
@Value("${local.server.port}")
private int tomcatPort;

@Before
public void setup() {
    RestAssured.port = tomcatPort;
}
```

Comment: I already wrote when(authService.authenticate(any(User.class))).thenReturn(user); like I said in the edit 1. But, it seemed fruitless. The user which you suggested to instantiate and give values to is being done in the Auth class. Even if I don't instantiate properly, I used Matcher.any(User.class) which means that it should work. The problem is somewhere in describing mocks/inject mocks/autowiring test rest template in springboot.

Comment: Can u defined restassured port and then try the same code.. I have edited my answer to include this.. I have tried something similar and it works using testresttemplate